# Java regex for string with fixed start and repeated blocks

Tags: java, regex

Consider a line of text like

```
"ab,""c"",""d"",""e"",""""
```

The above line has a fixed start `"ab` and then it repeats blocks like

```
,""<non-quote(s)>""
```

(i.e., comma, followed by 2 double quotes, followed by 0 or more non-quotes, followed by 2 quotes), with possibilities for empty blocks (i.e., 4 consecutive quotes `""""`).

A regex like

- (?:,"+([^",]*)"+)

will match all blocks (i.e., everything from the first comma, inclusive), but leave out the fixed start.

Using an "or" (`|`) clause like

- (?:"([^,]+)|,"+([^",]*)"+)

works, but with 2 groups, out of which #1 is the fixed start in the first round of `matcher.find()` and `null` in the rest, whereas #2 is `null` in the first invocation and correctly populated in all other invocations.

Is there an efficient `Java` regex which produces a single group, which, for consecutive invocations of `matcher.find()` returns first the fixed start and then each of the repeatitive blocks?

Comment: Why not get a substring without the first beginning and split by `"",""`?

Comment: What have you tried, BTW? Regex is processed from left to right, and the same text cannot be read from the same position twice. Thus, what you ask for is not possible with pure regex.

Comment: The use case the question relates to, does not offer string manipulation, only passing a regex and extracting the groups via `find()`. I have tried looking for the blocks, which of course leaves the fixed start out. Using an "or" (`|`) clause does not seem to work, either. Thanks.

Comment: When a `Matcher#find()` is executed, the regex engine moves its internal index to the right and there is no way for it to return as a first part something that has already been matched before.

Comment: Of course. A regex with "or" that would only match the fixed start in the first pass and then match the rest, would work, but it produces 2 groups per round.

Comment: Please add what you tried to the question and describe the limitations you have, and provide the necessary output. It is rather unclear what you need now.

Comment: I added the 2 simple regexes tried. Thanks.

Comment: The accepted solution does not match the fixed start, and you seem to want something other than groups. You just wanted to get substrings inside quotes. as far as I understood. The requirement has not been formulated well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the pattern you are looking for:

```
"{1,2}([^",]*)(?:"")?(?:,|$)
```

Or as a Java string:

```
\"{1,2}([^\",]*)(?:\"\")?(?:,|$)
```

Then you get the desired values in **group 1** (the only captured group).

Please have in mind that this regex is only useful for splitting a string, but not for validating it. Also it doesn't supports values with **[ , ]** or **[ " ]** in them.

Here you have a usage example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class MatcherTest {
    private static String text = "\"ab,\"\"c\"\",\"\"d\"\",\"\"e\"\",\"\"\"\"";

    private static String patternString = "\"{1,2}([^\",]*)(?:\"\")?(?:,|$)";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("'" + matcher.group(1) + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost there, but it produces an extra empty group at the end, with a single quote. Thanks and +1 anyway. :-)

Comment: There was a mistake in the code example which is now corrected, besides that I have tested this regex [here](https://ideone.com/4Di6xm) and [here](http://fiddle.re/04ew06) without any problems.

Comment: I also used RegexPlanet to test and it produces the extra empty string at the end. Your regex seems to work, however if you modify it at the end to `"{1,2}([^",]*)(?:"")?(?:,|$)` it works even for my example strings (which are more complicated that the one posted in the above question). I accept your answer as a solution, though, and thanks very much! :-)

Comment: Let me know if this one works better: `(?:^"|"")([^",]*)(?:"")?(?:,|$)`